# Is Dropbox smooth and stable on Kubuntu 16?

Tags: kubuntu, dropbox

So far it SEEMS to be working, but I don't know if i trust it.

I encountered a few minor snags when installing, but I got it working by just following the prompts in terminal then following the prompts when I first opened it.

But in the process I searched for advice on the minor snags, and I found a few things which said that dropbox needs GNOME desktop (when Kubuntu has KDE) or Dropbox needs nautilus which Kubuntu is not safely compatible with.

So far the only issue I can SEE is that the icon in the taskbar is just a cloud rather than the usual distinctive box... but that's not actually a problem. Can I trust it for stability?

It launches dropbox on startup even though I told it not to, but that's not a total deal breaker... but it is kinda a bad sign.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Kubuntu 16 with the Plasma desktop and Dropbox is working perfectly. I have the cloud icon with a little checkmark that indicates whether the Dropbox site is up to date with your local Dropbox folder (changes color). Whenever I want to send something to Dropbox, I just drag it to my local Dropbox folder and it is copied to the Dropbox website. Never seen it fail. If you tell it not to launch at startup, you don't get the convenience of the local Dropbox folder.

Comment: on windows i can start it after startup, i get the folder, it just doesn't sync till i tell it to. I can also mouse over the taskbar icon and see how long i have left till it's finished syncing.